# Token for odd number of spaces

Tags: token, lexer, javacc

I'm trying to create a token for an odd number of spaces. This is what I have currently

```
TOKEN : {
< SPACE: " " > 
| < ODDSPACE: <SPACE> ((<SPACE>)(<SPACE>))* >
}

void Start() :
{}
{  
    <ODDSPACE>
}
```

This is fine for 3, 5, 7...etc spaces, but fails when I try using only once space. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See question 3.3 of the JavaCC FAQ. http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.3

> There are three golden rules for picking which regular expression to use to identify the next token:
>
> 1. The regular expression must describe a prefix of the remaining input stream.
> 2. If more than one regular expression describes a prefix, then a regular expression that describes the longest prefix of the input stream is used. (This is called the "maximal munch rule".)
> 3. If more than one regular expression describes the longest possible prefix, then the regular expression that comes first in the .jj file is used.

In your case rule 3 applied.  You can rewrite `start` as

```
void Start() :
{}
{  
    <ODDSPACE> | <SPACE> 
}
```